# Block not returning anything in module developement Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework, module, block

Hi i have just start learning magento module development and for this i am following the pierefay tutorial and i found this very useful. However i am following his tutorial step by step  in the fourth step

http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54#comment-1507

i got stuck at one place
in the block file i have following code and it is suggested it will return entries from database

```
<?php
class Pfay_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
        //on initialize la variable
        $retour='';
        /* we are doing the query to select all elements of the pfay_test table (thanks to our model test/test and we sort them by id_pfay_test */
     $collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()->setOrder('id_pfay_test','asc');

         /* then, we check the result of the query and with the function getData() */
        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
            echo  $retour .= $data->getData('nom').' '.$data->getData('prenom')
                     .' '.$data->getData('telephone').'<br />';
         }
         //i return a success message to the user thanks to the Session.
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($retour);
         print_r($retour);
      }
}
```

but it is not returning anything.
When i copy this code in my indexcontroller or phtml file it shows the list of entries from database.

Can anybody tell me how can i use this code in block file to return data

thanks

Comment: First check if the collection return anything

Comment: check if this returning anything Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the solution by calling the

```
<?php
   echo $this->methodblock();
 ?>
```

in phtml file